# Fitting a squared exponential covariance function to data

Tags: covariance, fitting, covariance-function

I have been given the task of calculating a squared exponential covariance function for some given data.

If I am calculating the covariance as a function of x,

(p(x)-E[p(x)])*(p(x')-E[p(x')]) = cov(x,x') = A*exp(-B*(x-x')^2).

My confusion is arising from the fact that the squared exponential function is either purely positive or purely negative (based on the value of A) while the LHS of the equation (the covariance) can take both positive and negative values depending on x and x'.

How would I find an appropriate A and B in this situation? I looked for hours on Google, but couldn't find a good example of a similar problem. Thanks!

**More context:** I have a 2D data, where as a function of x and y (two independent coordinates), I have a function f(x,y). My task is to do Gaussian process regression assuming that the mean has the form a+b*(||(x,y)-(0,0)||). That is, the mean is a function of the L2 distance of the point from the origin. The covariance function has the form of Aexp(-B(distance)^2) where 'distance' refers to the L2 distance between the points we are trying to calculate the covariance of.

My first task is to calculate the parameters a,b and A,B from the data. In this context, what does the covariance between two points mean? And why is the covariance function (commonly used from what I see on the internet) always positive or negative, but doesn't take both?

Comment: A and B are typically found by some estimation procedure. I don’t see any problem here, the covariance between two variable also is either negative, zero or positive. In case it’s negative, A will be negative, and so on.

Comment: But A has to be positive because the variance (x = x') is always positive, right?

Comment: Perhaps you have to give us more context about the question. But If you are modelling the variance of a variable, then yes A has to be positive, if you are modelling the covariance of X and X^' then A can be anything.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with more details

Comment: @utobi That is not the case, because this is a covariance *function.*  It cannot be valid unless $A=\operatorname{Var}(p(x))$ is positive.  BTW, fitting this *Gaussian* covariance model to 2D data is a delicate matter. Except in special circumstances it's usually a bad model -- it makes an extremely strong assumption about the differentiability of the underlying surface -- and small changes in the parameter estimates can have profound effects on predictions.

Comment: Oh I see now. You are right @whuber, it's the covariance of a Gaussian process...